# Host Azure files on IIS

Tags: iis, azure-files

I have followed [this](https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/azurefile) article and i didn't miss any step except the sharing config which i don't need. Like the article says, i have create a local user with the same name and password.On ‘Test Settings’ option ,‘Authentication’ passed (ignored the ‘Authorization’ error as mentioned )

I'm able to see the azure files in the content view of the virtual directory. But when i browse, it says

```
HTTP Error 500.19 
"The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
```

It is actually looking for a config file at the UNC path `\\staticcontent.file.core.windows.net\repo`.

Comment: Hey @Batman welcome to SO! In order to make this question useful you will need to provide more details. You mention that you can see the files in one view but not the other. What have you tried? Can you confirm that the permissions are correct? Are the username and password being passed correctly?

Comment: i can see the files in the content view in iis. Yes the permissions are correct. I can view the shared files from windows explorer. The username password is correct as when i click "Test settings " option, authentication is passed.

Comment: What is the UNC path?

Comment: "\\staticcontent.file.core.windows.net\repo" , name changed but it looks similar to that. No drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I had followed. Reach out to me at renash at microsofyt dot com if you have questions.

http://fabriccontroller.net/deploying-a-load-balanced-high-available-ftp-server-with-azure-files/

Step 1
configure an availability set for Windows virtual machines in the classic deployment model
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/configure-availability

Step 2

```
$vm1name =  'cltkdemovm1'
$vm2name =  'cltkdemovm2'
$servicename= 'cltkdemodomain'
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Windows Azure Internal Consumption"
$vm = Get-AzureVM -Name $vm1name -ServiceName $servicename
.\Add-AzureFtpEndpoints.ps1 $vm 21 10000 10050
$vm = Get-AzureVM -Name $vm2name  -ServiceName $servicename
.\Add-AzureFtpEndpoints.ps1 $vm 21 20000 20050
```

Step3
On vm1:

```
Install-FTP.bat cltkdemoftp <storageaccountname> <storageaccountkey>  <sharename> 21 10000 10050 <VMIPAddress>
```

Example:

```
Install-FTP.bat cltkdemoftp cltkdemosa  <storage account key>==  ftp 21 10000 10050 40.76.29.172
```

On vm2:

```
Install-FTP.bat ctdemoftp cltkdemosa <storage account key>==  ftp 21 20000 20050 <VMIPAddress>
```

Example:

```
Install-FTP.bat cltkdemoftp cltkdemosa  <storage account key>==  ftp 21 20000 20050 40.76.29.172
```

Step4
Added sa to IISUser Group
Add sa to Application Pool ->Poolname->advancedsetting->identiy

On VM2
Added sa to IISUser Group
Add sa to Application Pool ->Poolname->advancedsetting->identiy